# Apple CareKit not able to navigate to OCKCareCardViewController

Tags: ios, swift3, carekit

I am trying to implement basic functionality in Apple CareKit Framework. But i am not able to navigate to OCKCareCardViewController.

Please find my code here on Github
https://github.com/sandesh271991/CareKitDemo

Please guide me where I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You are doing    `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(careCardViewController, animated: true)`, but your ViewController does not have a navigationController. 
Add a navigation controller in your storyboard, make it initial view controller, and make your ViewController as its rootViewController, and your code should work fine (See the image attached).[Navigation Controller to ViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRrml.png)